# Need help to change vertical spacing and margin in my messy document

Tags: margins, line-spacing

Over time I have added a number of commands at the beginning of my document and I am getting lost and I now fail to simply modify vertical spacing and margin.

## Current Document

Here are my packages and things

```
% ---------------------------
DOCUMENTCLASS
% ---------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{scrartcl}

% --------------------------
BIBLIOGRAPHY
% ---------------------------
\usepackage[round,mcite]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% --------------------------
INPUTSTRUCTURE
% ---------------------------
\input{structure.tex}

% --------------------------
OTHER
% ---------------------------
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\hypersetup{citecolor=brown}
\hyphenation{Fortran hy-phen-ation}
```

and here is my structure.tex

```
\usepackage[
nochapters, % Turn off chapters since this is an article        
beramono, % Use the Bera Mono font for monospaced text (\texttt)
eulermath,% Use the Euler font for mathematics
pdfspacing, % Makes use of pdftex‚Äô letter spacing capabilities via the microtype package
dottedtoc % Dotted lines leading to the page numbers in the table of contents
]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style

\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{Figures/}} % Set the default folder for images

\usepackage{enumitem} % Required for manipulating the whitespace between and within lists

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{subfig} % Required for creating figures with multiple parts (subfigures)

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % For including math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\usepackage{varioref} % More descriptive referencing

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition} % Define theorem styles here based on the definition style (used for definitions and examples)
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{plain} % Define theorem styles here based on the plain style (used for theorems, lemmas, propositions)
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{remark} % Define theorem styles here based on the remark style (used for remarks and notes)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hypersetup{
%draft, % Uncomment to remove all links (useful for printing in black and white)
colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,
urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, % Link colors
pdftitle={}, % PDF title
pdfauthor={\textcopyright}, % PDF Author
pdfsubject={}, % PDF Subject
pdfkeywords={}, % PDF Keywords
pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX}, % PDF Creator
pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis} % PDF producer
}
```

## Question

How can I modify vertical spacing (in between lines spacing) and margins?

## What I tried

The following does not seem to have any impact on the document

```
\usepackage[body={4.8in,7.5in},
 top=1.2in, left=1.8in]{geometry}
```

Same for

```
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
```

I tried to switch from `scrartcl` to `article` but I did not achieve much.

I also tried things like

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

but I often ended up receiving an error message although I failed to understand why and when.

Comment: I've used `\linespread{1.1}` with the koma scrlttr class to increase line spacing (aka leading)...you might try something similar. Also, I don't think geometry works with koma class items, so to change the margins you might use something like `\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}` and 
`\setlength{\textheight}{10in}` etc

Comment: `\linespread` works well! For the margins, `\setlength` seems to modify the right and bottom margin but not the left and top margins. Thanks

Comment: For the top and bottom margins, you should use the `vmargin` and `hmargin` options from [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).  Note that if another package is change the page layout, you may want to use the `\geometry` command just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Indeed I did not place my commands at the right place. Moving  the commands I listed in `What I tried` right before `\begin{document}` solved my problem. Thank you! Do you guys want to make an answer out of your comments?

Comment: @JP-Ellis Answer? Duplicate? Or close for other reason?

Comment: You are playing havoc with KOMA's stuff. Take a look at the documentation to find out some of the things you are breaking. Note that the class uses A4 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have:

```
% ---------------------------
DOCUMENTCLASS
% ---------------------------
```

This is missing a comment character before `DOCUMENTCLASS` which will result in an error (though I'm hoping that this is just an error in copy/pasting).

Now regarding modifying the margins, as you figured out, it's easiest to use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.  Note that if another package is changing the page layout, you may want to use the `\geometry` command just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\geometry{vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm}
\begin{document}
```

Regarding the spacing between lines, Chris already provided an answer in his comment using `\linespread{1.1}` for example .  You can also have a look at the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setscape) package which provides `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` and `doublespacing` (though that's typically used for creating proof-reading copies).

Finally, you should have a look through the log file, because you are getting a lot of warnings.  For example, the KOMA classes (such as `scrartcl`) provide a lot of features which overlap with other packages (cfr also mentioned that in his comment just then).  The overlap of these packages can result in features being partially overriden and then neither packages working properly.

Finally, you should typically prefer the [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package over the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package which you are using.